# Need help finding current in a resistive circuit

Tags: current

Find the current \$I_A\$in the circuit below  [image]

So far I have started the problem by combing the 1 kohm and 2 kohm to create a 2/3 resistance.

I am currently stuck on how to find the current based on the placement of IA.

How can I relate the 4 kohm to the 7mA?

Comment: This is a very simple problem because the two current sources are in parallel.  Simply calculate the total current, then find the voltage across the network.  The rest is simple.

Comment: Given that you have combined the 1k and 2k, do you see how it's also possible to combine the 5k with the 2/3k? And so on...

Comment: Why only combine the 1k and 2k resistances? Why not also add the 4k? All three resistances are connected to the same nodes at both ends :) Just because your instructor drew one of them to the left of the 7mA current source makes no difference...

Comment: Move the current sources to one side and the resistors to the other, does that help? 7mA down + 3mA up = 4mA down, 4k//1k//2k//5k = something less that 1k

Comment: @DwayneReid too long, the easiest way is to apply the superposition principle, it literally take 3 computations

Comment: Where is the source of current? or points to attach the power supply?

Answer (score 1):

Your first step is correct, it yields 2/3K ohm. Use the Kirchoff's current law to proceed further. Current through the 5K resistor is the combination of current "A" and 3mA, that is 3mA+Ia, call this I1. Now write the voltage equation across the 5K resistor in terms of this current, (3mA+Ia)5K. Using this voltage, write the equation for the current through the 2/3K, [(3mA+Ia)5K]/(2/3), call this I2.

Also, use the same voltage equation to write the equation for the current through the 4K resistor. Assume this current is flowing downwards, it combines with the 7mA, call this I3.

Now use the I3 and I2 to calculate the Ia. I didn't counter check whether my work accurate or not, but this can serve as the guideline for you.

[image]

Comment: It's a lot easier if you lump the 1k, 2k, and 4k resistors together. There's no reason to treat them differently just because the instructor drew one of them to the left of the 7mA current source. You fell for the "trap" :)

Comment: You got the point there. Will you pls post your answer for others to see?

Comment: I don't think we're here to do people's homework.

Comment: That solution is way too long....

Comment: The question asked for a solution, not a short solution particularly.... If you can do it  in a single step, pls show us how.

Comment: Superposition principle = 2 current divider + 1 addition ...